# Estimators of correlated linear regression model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

Suppose there are two regression models, $(i = 1,2,\cdots,500)$

**Model 1)** $ y_{1i} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \epsilon_{1i}$

**Model 2)** $ y_{2i} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i} + \epsilon_{2i} $,
where

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 
x_2 \end{bmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ 20\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} \epsilon_1 \\ \epsilon_2 \end{bmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

I set true $\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2$ = 1, 1, 1.
**In this setting, $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ are correlated.**

I obtained ols regression estimators of Model 1, Model 2,

**Model 3)** $ y_{2i} = \phi_1 y_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i} + \epsilon_i  (\epsilon = \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2)$

and

**Model 4)** $ \begin{bmatrix} y_{1i}  \\ y_{2i} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_{1i} & 0 \\ 1 & x_{1i} & x_{2i} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \beta_0 \\ \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \epsilon_{1i} \\ \epsilon_{2i} \end{bmatrix} $ (joint model)

When I made 1,000 samples of estimators, the monte carlo mean and standard errors of estimators were
[image]

My questions are,

**1. why model 3's estimators are biased,** although it has small standard errors?

**2. Why model 4's estimators have smaller standard errors than model 2?**

Is there way to derive it analytically?